# WPF String Formatting "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Tags: wpf, string, datetime, locale

I get this error when trying to have a WPF application try to format a string field as a datetime object:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Date, StringFormat={}{0:dd-MM-yyyy}}" Header="Date"/>
```

And the error I seem to be getting is:

"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

How do you fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience this error is caused by a lack of a set locale in the Window header, that is:

```
xml:lang="en-GB"
```

Or whatever is appropriate needs to be inserted into the Window header and that should fix the problem.